# How make a job depend from other job in previous stage

Tags: gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, jobs

I have same stages :

```
stage: 
  - A
  - B

job1:
 stage: A
job2: 
 stage: A
job3 : 
 stage: B
```

the sequence must be job1 -> job3 -> job2  and each job depend from previous job.
job1 and job3 is working fine but as job2 depend from job3 (previous stage) is not working.
I get an error 'job2 job: need job3 is not defined in current or prior stages'

Any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [needs keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) to create an acyclic relationship between one job and another - which also lets you make the job depend on any job from any previous stage - however in your case you don't need to do that.

Use the needs keyword for more advanced scenarios (like ignoring job failures from the proceeding stage).

Keep in mind that all jobs that share a stage will be run (by default) in parallel. This should work just fine:

```yaml
stages:
 - first
 - second

job1:
  stage: first
  script: echo "this job will run"
job2:
  stage: first
  script: echo "at the same time as this job"
job3:
  stage: second
  script: echo "this job will run after all jobs in the first stage succeed"
```

Your question was

> "How make a job depend from other job in previous stage"

and the above example answers that question. However in your description you wrote

> "...the sequence must be job1 -> job3 -> job2"

Which, based on that description, could be achieved like so:

```yaml
 - first
 - second
 - third

job1:
  stage: first
  script: echo "this job will run during the first stage"
job2:
  stage: third
  script: echo "this job will run during the third stage"
job3:
  stage: second
  script: echo "this job will run during the second stage"
```

The above config would guarantee that none of your jobs execute in parallel and proceed in the sequence you described. You still wouldn't need the `needs` keyword in this case and the config would be easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo in your code. It has to be **stages** and not **stage**.

Below is the working code.

```
stages: 
  - A
  - B

job1:
  stage: A
  script:
   - echo "Job 1"

job2: 
 stage: A
 script:
   - echo "Job 2"
 needs:
  - job1

job3 : 
 stage: B 
 script:
   - echo "Job 3"
 needs:
   - job2
```

I had to remove the tags: as it was internal to my runner.
See t he dependency is shown clearly in the Visualize tab.
[image]

And I validated that it triggers job1 first and job3 waits for it.

Comment: I need to trigger job1 then job3 then job2(it must waiting job3 until finish) ..

Comment: I see, no that doesn't seems to be working. Doesn't make sense also to depend on the job in future stage.  I think you need to revisit your requirement.